# traverse array of form element names with different indexs

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dom, html-input

Hey guys was hoping you could help me out

I have a form, with a dynamic number of specific input fields with an array name having a unique but random index.

Now I want to traverse these fields but having trouble getting them, traversing them, etc.

I.e Have something like this

```
<input type='text' name='resources[2]' />
<input type='text' name='resources[4]' />
<input type='text' name='resources[5]' />
```

now want to do something like  "for each input with name=resources, do something with its value and index number."

Oh and am  trying to do this with jquery....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use wild cards to match pattern in selectors, here you can use ^ (for start with), You can read more about wildcards **[here](http://www.thewebgoodies.com/2010/12/24/jquery-wildcard-selectors-complete/)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/osizak/1/edit)**

```
$('input[name^=resources]').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).val());
})
```

Comment: yup that worked :)...Thanks.. but what exactly is the "^"? how does this selector work.

Comment: Updated my answer, ^ is used for startsWith